# SSL Server on Windows CE 4.2

Tags: ssl, windows-ce

Does the the web server on Windows CE 4.2 support TLS 1.0?  From this documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms836811.aspx#wincesec_topic6

It looks like Window CE 4.2 does support SSL 3.1 (TLS 1.0), but when I try to connect it does not work.  Is there just something I'm missing?

Thanks.